# Lock windows resolution, orientation and scale

Tags: windows-10, resolution, intel-graphics, display-settings, screenresolution

How to prevent Windows 10 from changing display resolution, orientation and scale % by it self?
Or if not possible, how to set them by a script at the boot time?
I'm managing 10+ computers connected to various screens and if there is HDMI problem or screen is slow to wake up from sleep, windows sometimes changes those values. When the screen is back, wrong values remain.
They are mostly intel Celeron or i3 with integrated Intel graphics chipset.

Edit / more info:
As this problem occurs only occasionally, it is difficult to troubleshoot. I did find many similar questions asked in the past 10 years, but no complete answer. All installations are fresh Windows 10 Pro with all updates.
The best explanation I've managed to find is:

> Every time you boot the machine, your video hardware drivers are
> loaded and caused to execute their initialization routine. Part of
> that task involves reading the EDID information from all connected
> monitors. If your video drivers fail at obtaining that information
> (which includes monitor preferred resolution) then monitor resolution
> is set to some value that somebody judged suitable for a "generic"
> monitor and you are given a limited set of other resolutions to choose
> from.

Case 1: PC connected via HDMI with big (8 x 2 meters) LED display controller. On Windows Display properties page it must have Scale and layout: 100% to show entire image. PC is automatically turned off at midnight and turned on each morning. At least once per month Scale and layout gets changed to 125% by it self.
I assume that display controller sometimes takes longer to turn on as it went to sleep and EDID is not available at the Windows boot time.

Case 2: Display orientation must be in portrait mode (1080 x 1920). It is connected to LCD screens via HDMI. I can't find the pattern when it happens as it is even less often, but sometimes after boot display is back to landscape mode (1920 x 1080).

The only tools I have found are 3rd party applications like QRes.exe and nircmd.exe which can set resolution, but not display orientation. Forcing resolution to 1080 x 1920 does not work.

I did manage just now to find one more tool from nirsoft: MultiMonitorTool.exe. It should be able to change display orientation, but there is still nothing for setting "Scale and layout"?

I'm aware that it might not be pure Windows problem and that graphic card drivers plays it's role. There should be a way to hardcode this settings and avoid temporary problems such as power failures or different boot times.

Comment: How to prevent Windows 10 from changing display resolution, ...... This is not something Windows does by itself.   Try updating Video and Power Drivers on affected machines.

Comment: Please explain the research you have done and what you've tried.